# Tensorflow: trying to get toy neural network to 'learn'

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Trying to get very simple ('toy') 2-layer neural network to build model, as a learning example to make sure the math flows correctly.

The model should learn that a '1' on the first and last feature equates to a '1' output.

```
features = []
features.append([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0]])
features.append([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0]])
features.append([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0]])
features.append([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0]])
features.append([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0]])
features.append([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0]])
features.append([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0]])
features.append([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0]])
features.append([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0]])
features.append([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0]])
features.append([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0]])
features.append([[1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0]])
features.append([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0]])
features.append([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0]])
# output of [1] of positions [0,4]==1
features.append([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1]])
features.append([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1]])
features.append([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1]])
features.append([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1]])
features.append([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1]])
features.append([[1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1]])
features.append([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1]])
features.append([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1]])
```

However I cannot get any error/cost to show up...

```
Epoch 3 completed out of 10 cost: 0.0
Epoch 5 completed out of 10 cost: 0.0
Epoch 7 completed out of 10 cost: 0.0
Epoch 9 completed out of 10 cost: 0.0
Accuracy: 1.0
```

Thanks in advance for having a quick look: [**here is the notebook**](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ugik/notebooks/blob/master/Tensorflow%20ANN.ipynb)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the output, it needed to be a 2-class array. Not sure why this is necessarily the case.

```
features.append([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0,1]])
features.append([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0,1]])
features.append([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0,1]])
features.append([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0,1]])
features.append([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0,1]])
```

the working notebook is [**here**](https://github.com/ugik/notebooks/blob/master/Tensorflow%20ANN.ipynb).